# Is there any latest technology which will replace Docker, Kubernetes in future?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, cloud, google-cloud-platform

What's the future of engineers starting career in tools like Docker, Kubernetes?

Comment: Bright or dull, it depends

Comment: Containerization will probably be replaced by the same thing that replaced the mainframe/timesharing systems and virtualization - some new iteration of the same idea but now better.

Comment: The idea of containerization is not going anywhere soon. Community rather than replacing the tool is building on existing tools like docker and LXC's to extend its power. Chance of improvement in tools might be in their efficiency and security.

Comment: If you want to see what is the future of engineers, read about SRE(site reliability engineering)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps serverless could substitute it, but it will be hard to predict. I would suggest to follow industry standards and run things using these tools in production to stay up to date. The most changes in all branches occur in IT. Having said this, every engineer has to learn new things everyday to stay up to date. Whether k8s and docker will be replaced? Probably yes, but on the other hand there are still VMs and on-premise hardware. Perhaps k8s and docker will be used less in the future, but when I do not know. I am not a fortune teller with a crystal ball.